# How can I change a tkinter label text to display key press information?

Tags: python, tkinter, pynput

I am trying to make it so that the user can use a hotkey to start/stop the program. I have a label to display what the hotkey is currently set to and a button to allow them to change it (I am using Pynput to detect keypresses).

The button is linked to the following code:

```
def set_Hotkey():

    def on_press(key):
        global hotkey
        hotkey = key
        listener.stop()
        
         key_label.config(text=f'{key}')
    
    def on_release(key):
        pass

    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

I have also tried using StringVar, and played around with setting the text to `str(key)` instead of `f'{key}'` all to no avail.

Whenever I run the program it starts up fine, and if I replace the `key_label.config()` line with `print(key)` or `print(str(key))` it does it no bother. However, when I try and set the label text to display what key got pressed, the program freezes and I'm forced to close it down. I don't get any form of error message in my console, it just freezes.

Can someone please explain what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you include more code from tkinter side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pynput.keyboard.Listener()` is also a thread, so calling `join()` will block `tkinter` mainloop.

Change:

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

to:

```
listener = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```